# javascript doesn't work after jquery .load

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, zeroclipboard

I have a `default.aspx` page which contains these elements:

1. Listview
2. Div ID = subview
3. Two copying buttons

When the user clicks on any of these buttons, I want to copy some text and make the clicked button disabled.

I did that. The copying functions are working and the disable style is working fine too on both buttons.

Each row of the listview has a link. If the user clicks on that link, I want to load another page `subview.aspx` using jquery `.load` function and put the result inside the div ID = subview

```
$('#subView').load('SubView.aspx?');
```

The subview page also contains two copying buttons.
These buttons can copy the correct text, However, they don't become disable when the user clicks any of them.

#### My Code

I included the `zeroclipboard.js` at the top of the `default.aspx`.
These are the two buttons inside the default.aspx:

```
   <button type="button" id="Button1" class="copyToBtn" type="button" data-clipboard-text="<%#Eval("Telephone")%>" title="Copy Phone">Copy Phone Number</button>
   <button type="button" id="Button3" class="copyToBtn" data-clipboard-text="<%#Eval("Surname")%>" title="Copy Surname">Copy Surname</button>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="zero/jjjj.js"></script>
```

These are the two buttons inside the subview.aspx

```
<button type="button" id="Button1" class="copyToBtn" type="button" data-clipboard-text="<%#Eval("Telephone")%>"title="Copy Phone">Copy Phone Number</button>
<button type="button" id="Button3" class="copyToBtn" data-clipboard-text="<%#Eval("Surname")%>" title="Copy Surname">Copy Surname</button>
<script type="text/javascript" src="zero/jjjj.js"></script>
```

This is the jjjj.js

```
var client = new ZeroClipboard(document.getElementById("Button1"), {
moviePath: "/zero/ZeroClipboard.swf"
});

client.on("load", function (client) {

client.on("complete", function (client, args) {

    $('.copyToBtn').each(function () {
        $(this).removeAttr('disabled').removeClass('ui-state-disabled');
    });

    if (this.id == "Button1") {
        $("#Button1").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    }
    else if (this.id == "Button3") {
        $("#Button3").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    }
    alert(this.id);
});
});

var client3 = new ZeroClipboard(document.getElementById("Button3"), {
moviePath: "/zero/ZeroClipboard.swf"
});

client3.on("load", function (client3) {

client3.on("complete", function (client3, args) {

    $('.copyToBtn').each(function () {
        $(this).removeAttr('disabled').removeClass('ui-state-disabled');
    });

    if (this.id == "Button1") {
        $("#Button1").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    }
    else if (this.id == "Button3") {
        $("#Button3").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    }
    alert(this.id);
});
});
```

**Note please** that the alert is just working on the default.aspx, not on the subview.aspx **thought the copying functions are completely working fine** in subview and default.aspx.

Help please

Comment: where you mentioned `$('#subView').load('SubView.aspx?');` ?

Comment: I can't really tell from your description, but if you are replacing DOM elements, then any prior event handlers on those DOM elements will be wiped out (they were attached to the old DOM elements that no longer exist).  You will either have to reattach the event handlers to the newly replaced DOM elements or switch to using delegated event handling where you rely on event propagation and attach the event to a parent object that is itself not replaced.

Comment: @samitha when the user clicks on a link inside any row of the listview there is a script which has that `.load`

Comment: @jfriend00 I know that. That is why I re included the `jjjj.js` into the subview.aspx (as mentioned in the question). Also, when I remove that script from subview.axps, the copying buttons stop working (IE: stop copying the text).

Comment: In my opinion, it's a bad practice to rely on scripts that are embedded in the dynamically loaded content.  Much better to have the scripts you need already in the page and just call them after you load the new content.  As I said above, I don't really follow exactly what you are doing or what your issue is from your description so just trying to provide helpful info.

Comment: @jfriend00 I am calling the script after loading the new content. Please check that the `jjjj.js` is included after in the last line of subview.aspx.

Comment: Like I said, I don't think it's a good practice to rely on scripts that are embedded in the dynamically loaded content.  It ends up trying to redeclare variables that already exist (from prior loads) and all sorts of things that might not actually cause trouble, but aren't considered good practices.  Anyway, I don't follow your issue so I'll step aside and hopefully someone else does.

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is that the problem is that the buttons in the main page have the same id as the buttons in the subview. The javascript doesn't know which #Button1 to disable, the old one or the new one. There are many other problems with the js also.

Comment: You suggest changing the IDs of the buttons inside the subview.aspx. Okay I will try that and update you. But please what are these mistakes in the script ?

Comment: I changed the IDs and still the same result which is the copying buttons are working but the style is not. I believe it is something about zeroclipboard library

Answer (score 0):

I think jfriend00 already answered this, but let me give it a try: if you are adding new elements dynamically, you need to attach event handlers to something that is there when the page itself loads and parses the javascript or reattach the handler.  This is a working example similar to what you want to do... (make sure your ZeroClipboard.min.js file and the .swf file are in the root directory where you are testing or change the script tag accordingly).

Create an html page with the body as follows:

```
<body>
    <button type="button" class="clip_button">Copy To Clipboard</button>
    <button type="button" class="clip_button">Copy This Too!</button>
    <!--new buttons will be appended inside the sublist div-->
    <div class="sublist">
    </div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="ZeroClipboard.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$( document ).ready(function() {
        var client;

        // Create a function that sets up your Zero Clipboard Instance
        var fnSetUpZCB = function () {
            // Every time we run this function, it will attach the event handler to the buttons with the class clip_button
            client = new ZeroClipboard( $('.clip_button') );

            client.on( 'ready', function(event) {           
                client.on( 'copy', function(event) {
                    event.clipboardData.setData('text/plain', event.target.innerHTML);
                });

                // On aftercopy is where we can manipulate the object that was clicked using event.target (in this case to disable the clicked button)
                client.on( 'aftercopy', function(event) {
                    event.target.disabled = true;
                    console.log('Copied text to clipboard: ' + event.data['text/plain']);
                    ZeroClipboard.destroy();

                    //I'm just appending a new button here so you can see that the dynamic elements are indeed getting the handler attached.  You could run your load function here.

                    $('.sublist').append('<button class="clip_button">Copy This Also!</button>');

                    //And, finally, after we load the new elements, we have to run our set up again to reinitialize any new items.
                    fnSetUpZCB();
                });
            });

            client.on( 'error', function(event) {
                // console.log( 'ZeroClipboard error of type "' + event.name + '": ' + event.message );
                ZeroClipboard.destroy();
            });
        }

        $('document').on('load', fnSetUpZCB()); 

    });
</script>
</body>
```